# mongodb execute multiple query concurrently

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a record if not exists in DB so for it first I am executing a query to find that particular record and if not exists, then execute anoter query to create it.

But the problem is if multiple requests comes at same time with same data. All requests try to find that record and because it is not yet created they all pass first condition and get created in DB.

for ex.
I have "start" and "end" fields in DB. I dont want any record having overlap timing so for it first I executes find query as below:

```
db.slots.find({
    from: {
        $lte: req.body.end
    },
    to: {
        $gte: req.body.from
    }
})
```

and if no record exists then I execute create query else I return reponse without creating the slot.

so If two requests comes at same time with same slot timing then both pass first find query as no record is yet created and then both get created so I want to implment something like a "lock".

Answer (score 0):

You can write one function. and inside the function do both the task. and make the function concurrent. by a global promise.

```
var mypromise;   
function myfunction(){
if(mypromise) return mypromise;

mypromise =  new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        ···
        resolve(value); // success
        mypromise = false;
    });
return mypromise;
```

}

Comment: I didn't get how to do it. can you please give any sample code for it?

Comment: I am not looking solution for single request. For single request It can be done easily without promise. In case of multiple request this code block will execute without creating lock on collection and duplicate record will get created.

Comment: No, the 2nd call to the function will, get the result of first call.

Comment: It will work for single call that means single call from client. If mulitple client calls it then this will not work and will allow to save duplicate data if the calls are on same time. Please read my question carefully.